# MoveWindow() missing in C++ OpenCV 2.3

Tags: c++, python, c, opencv

I am using the C++ version of OpenCV 2.3 and am struggling to do a basic task. What I would like to do is create a window and move it to a specific location on the screen using for example:

```
cv::namedWindow("My Window", 1);
cv::MoveWindow("My Window", 10, 10);
```

However, it appears that the MoveWindow() function is not available. From the OpenCV 2.3 documentation ([link](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow)) there appears to be C and Python implementations, but no C++. Does this mean there is a better way to be doing this?

From the relevant section of the documentation:

```
MoveWindow
==========
Moves window to the specified position
--------------------------------------
C: void cvMoveWindow(const char* name, int x, int y)

Python: cv.MoveWindow(name, x, y) → None

Parameters:

- name – Window name
- x – The new x-coordinate of the window
- y – The new y-coordinate of the window
```

---

**RESOLVED:** As of the latest version of OpenCV, there is now a `cv::MoveWindow("const string& winname, int x, int y)` function. Reference [here](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html#movewindow).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are supposed to use the C function for this:

```
cvMoveWindow(const char* name, int x, int y);
```

You can verify this info by downloading [OpenCV 2.3 for *nix](http://tenet.dl.sourceforge.net/project/opencvlibrary/opencv-unix/2.3/OpenCV-2.3.0.tar.bz2), and under the *C++ samples* directory `OpenCV-2.3.0/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/Basic/` search for a file named **Drawing_1.cpp**. It uses the C++ interface for everything.. **except**, moving the window.

Looks like the C++ interface doesn't have a method for this task.