# Automatically tile/arrange windows created with OpenCV (HighGUI)

Tags: c, opencv, window

I'm creating windows for debugging like this:

```
cvNamedWindow("a",0); cvShowImage("a", imageA);
cvNamedWindow("b",0); cvShowImage("b", imageB);
cvNamedWindow("c",0); cvShowImage("c", imageC);
```

OpenCV creates all these windows in the exact same spot, which is not very practical, since only one of them is visible unless you move them around.

Can I make OpenCV automatically arrange the windows so that all of them can be seen (like a tiling window manager)? Or do I have to do this myself using `cvMoveWindow`?

Comment: Use cvMoveWindow - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570205/movewindow-missing-in-c-opencv-2-3

Comment: @MartinBeckett: I know about that, I was wondering if there's a way to do this automatically?

Comment: No, showWindow is really only meant to test your image processing algorithm, not to create real display applications

Comment: Fortunately, for Python (the question is for C), you may use `pyplot` to show multiple images, though you have to convert the unusual OpenCV bgr order to common rgb used by `matplotlib`. [Example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2014/11/03/display-matplotlib-rgb-image/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is impossible - there's no such feature in [User Interface](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/user_interface.html) (I also was wondering about such functionality a month ago).

You have to manualy set window(s) position by calling `MoveWindow` - this is the only solution.